# Preventing automatic population of circular navigation properties in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, circular-reference

I have a problem when retrieving entities which have a circular reference. My entity navigation properties are not lazy loaded, so I would expect them to return null unless specifically included in a query, however I've found that when there is a circular reference between two entities this isn't the case and instead a recursive hierarchy is returned.

For example, let's say we have two entities `UserEntity` and `PostEntity`. A `UserEntity` may have many posts, but a post must only have a single `UserEntity`. So, the configuration is as follows:

```
// UserEntity configuration
HasMany(u => u.Posts)
  .WithRequired(p => p.User);
```

If I query the database for either a `UserEntity` or a `PostEntity` without using `Include()` on the respective `Posts` or `User` navigation properties, the navigation properties are null as expected.

However, if I query for a `UserEntity` and include its `PostEntity`s, an circular hierarchy is returned, even though I never requested that the `PostEntity.User` navigation property be populated:

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
  var user = await db.Users
    .Include(u => u.Posts)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(u => u.ID == 0);

  // The [UserEntity] contains a list of [PostEntitiy]s
  //   each with the [UserEntity] each with a list of [PostEntitiy]s...
  //     and so on.
}
```

This isn't too much trouble, but when a list of `PostEntity`s are retrieved and their `UserEntity`s are included things get very weird:

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
  var posts = await db.Posts
    .Include(p => p.User)
    .SingleOrDefaultAsync(p => p.ID == 0);

  // This throws a [System.InvalidOperationException]:
  // "Sequence contains more than one element"
  // How can this be? The ID is unique.

  var posts = await db.Posts
    .Include(p => p.User)
    .Where(p => p.ID == 0)
    .ToListAsync();

  // This returns several copies of the PostEntity
  //   which should be unique in the database. Is
  //   this a side effect of the circular reference?
}
```

Obviously getting rid of the circular reference would fix this, but there are several reasons why keeping it is beneficial, if possible. **Why is EntityFramework returning this circular hierarchy despite only a single, one-way relationship being requested with `Include()`, and why is this resulting in several `PostEntity`s being returned when their `UserEntity`s are included?**

Comment: Did you map your primary key with either attributes or fluent api? Also the circular reference, are you noticing it in code or in debugger?

Comment: Yes, I'm using fluent API for all of my configuration and the primary keys are properly mapped. The database is code first and other than this circular reference issue it works perfectly.

The circular reference is by design, however I never intend to retrieve a recursive hirarchy - i.e. I want either a post with it's user, OR a user with all of its posts. What's returned is a recursive hirarchy of users with posts with a user with posts... etc. This is visible in the debugger and also seems to effect the results of queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try projecting your entities into DTOs to work around this. Use [projection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738447(v=vs.110).aspx) into some type that does not have such references and avoid the exception.

In other words, pick up just the properties that you need from the EF model, not adding fields which are nested complex types that also have properties that point back to the same object and thus create circular references

```
using (var db = new MyDbContext())
{
    var posts = db.Posts
        .Include(p => p.User)
        .Where(p => p.ID == 0)
        .Select(p => new PostsDTO
        {
            Name = p.Name,
            Username = p.User.Username
        });
}
```

Comment: Using a DTO (or just projecting to a dynamic object) does fix the issues I've been having, however I'm dealing with quite large, complex entities and many, many different queries. Is there a way to simplify this process at all, preferably avoiding the manual mapping of values to properties? Otherwise I'm looking at hours of work, potentially.

Comment: As painful as this may be, I think it is benefitial to map your domain entities to a DTO. For a start, you don't have these circular reference issues, and secondly you dont expose you domain objects to the business / presentation layer. If your maps are tricky (or tedious, trivial mappings), consider using [automapper iqueryable extensions](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Queryable-Extensions) which do these projections for you.